# textfield with actionperformed actionlistner

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlabel, jtextfield

I have a jTextField and a jLabel. And I want to get data from database to my label automatically after user finished typing.

```
subcode_txt.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            Object obj=e.getSource();
            if(obj==subcode_txt){
            jst=subcode_txt.getText();
            try{

            rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from facultydtls where sub_code like '"+jst+"'");
            rs.next();
            faculty_lab.setText(rs.getString("f_name"));
            sem_lab.setText(rs.getString("sem"));
            subject_lab.setText(rs.getString("sub"));
            department_lab.setText(rs.getString("dept"));

            rs.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ewt){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Subject Code");
        }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to react on user input, a `DocumentListener` is a better approach then a `KeyListener`
2. You could opt for an `ActionListener`, which will be triggered when the user hits <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. You should not perform database queries on the Event Dispatch Thread. Use a worker thread instead. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information
4. The `close` statement should be placed in a `finally` block

That being said, what exactly are you asking ?

Comment: I did that with DocumentListner. But showmessagedailog "Invalid Subject Code" each time when I typed a letter

Comment: @SubratPatnaik The `DocumentListener` is triggered on each update of the contents of the text field. If you want to only react when the user hits enter, you need an `ActionListener`

Comment: even after use DocumentListener I have the same problem. Can you please give  any example related to my problem...Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Using a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) is the preferred approach for handling text events for `JTextComponents` in Swing.

Database queries demand significant resources and should be done outside the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) to prevent the UI from 'freezing'. Have a look at using `SwingWorker` in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564266/how-to-stop-a-swingworker).

Note that loading data for every `DocumentEvent` could potentially send a large amount of unnecessary requests to the database. There are 2 possible solutions:

- Data caching using a framework such as [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) - optimally loads data.
- While somewhat different from your requirement, you could use a load `JButton` to load the data when the full `String` has been provided by the user.

**Update:**

**In the short term:**

Add SQL wildcards characters to your query to match partial strings:

```
st.executeQuery("Select * from facultydtls where sub_code like '%" + jst + "%'");
```

**In the long term:**

Use `PreparedStatement`. It has the following benefits:

- Protects against SQL injection attacks, especially given that the user can enter a string that is part of the SQL query.
- `PreparedStatement` placeholder characters will take of any required string quotes.

Comment: @SubratPatnaik I would say that you need to add SQL wildcard characters. See update.

Comment: even after use DocumentListener I have the same problem. Can you please give  any example related to my problem...Thank You

Comment: even after use DocumentListener I have the same problem. Can you please give  any example related to my problem...Thank You