# How to make button click block in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, synchronous

I am very new to Swing.

I have

```
itemActionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {
        itemAction();
    }
});
```

But when the button is clicked, instead of running this action on another thread, I would like the parent's form's thread to wait until it the action is completed before refreshing, allowing additional clicks, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: I thought you were. Running the action from inside the actionPerformed will continue to block the EDT. You could disable the e button (on the click), run the action in a SwingWorker and rentable the button from the SwingWorker's done method

Comment: Paul can you see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083768/stop-cancel-swingworker-thread

Comment: As has been pointed out, I am running in the main thread here. It turns out that I am calling `itemAction()` indirectly from a TimerTask elsewhere. To get `itemAction()` to run on the main thread, I had to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in the ActionListener executes on the EDT, which prevents the GUI from repainting and responding to other events.

If you have a long running task and you don't want to block the EDT then you need to use another Thread.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and a solution by using a SwingWorker.