# How to update jprogress bar

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I have a simple JForm and a JDialog in my application. JDialog box contains a JProgressBar eliment and I'put a method in the JDialog as,

```
 public void updateProgress(int val){
        prgProgress.setValue(val); //prgProgress-> name of the JProgressBar
    }
```

to update the progress bar.

When I try to update the progress bar in my JDialog from the JForm, JProgressBar doesn't update as expected please tell me what could be the error,

Ex.

```
public class Status extends javax.swing.JDialog{
 private javax.swing.JProgressBar prgProgress = new javax.swing.JProgressBar;
.....

public void updateProgress(int val){
            prgProgress.setValue(val); //prgProgress-> name of the JProgressBar
        }

.....

}

public class MyForm extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
    Status s = new Status();
    s.setVisible(true);
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        s.updateProgress(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), Swing is single threaded and nothing happends if you update GUI out of EDT, you have to implement [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for updating [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html), example with descriptions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114890/714968)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I can't see from your code above showing that you have added the `JProgressBar` into the `JDialog`, but I assume you have done so.
Secondly, you didn't set the maximum value of the `JProgressBar`, from either constructor or member function `setMaximum()`. This might be a reason of showing no progress.

See Also:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: I've set the maximum value of the jprogressbar but, still got the same issue.

Comment: To clarify the question, did the JProgressBar show up on the JDialog, i.e. a bar with zero progress is showing?

Comment: Then, try to use a Thread to set the JDialog visible. It's because JDialog will block the current thread which should be owned by the Form after it is set to visible.

Comment: OK I've found the error, I have make the JDialogs' setModel=true, once I removed that line progress is displayed fine. but I wonder why it is not updated when setModel=true is true.