# JProgressBar Animation in a Table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jprogressbar

I have the following Problem:

I have a JTable which shows me the progress of a command. I have 2 sort of commands. Determined and indetermined commands.

If i only have indetermined progressbars in the table the progress is shown correct.
but if i have one determined progressbars in it, the other indetermined wont be animated.

Here is my code:

```
class ProgressBarRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    /** The bar. */
    private JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar() {
        public boolean isDisplayable() {
            return true;
        };
    };

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        ProgressBarInfo pbi = (ProgressBarInfo) value;
        if (pbi.getType() == Progress.LS) {
            if (pbi.getValue() == -1) {
                bar.setIndeterminate(false);
                bar.setValue(0);
                bar.setString("Progress ended");
            } else {
                bar.setIndeterminate(true);
                bar.setString(pbi.getValue() + " " + pbi.getText());
            }
            bar.setStringPainted(true);

            return bar;
        } else if (pbi.getType() == Progress.SCP) {
            if (pbi.getValue() == -1) {
                bar.setIndeterminate(false);
                bar.setValue(0);
                bar.setString("Progress ended");
            } else {
                bar.setValue(pbi.getValue());
                bar.setString(pbi.getValue() + "% " + pbi.getText());
            }
            bar.setIndeterminate(false);
            bar.setStringPainted(true);
        }
        return bar;
    }
}
```

The Table is updated every 10 milliseconds by a swingworker thread, so don't mind about that.

Comment: Why two `return bar` statements?

Comment: Just to be sure that he returns after setting the bar to indetermoinate mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The internal state of the progressBar (determinate vs. indeterminate) is very different - switching between them *on the same instance* might be the reason. Try to use one instance for each

```
public class MyRenderer ....
    JProgressBar determinate;
    JProgressBar indeterminate; 

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(...) {
         if (value.isDeterminate) {
           ...
           return determinate;
         }
         ....
         return undeterminate
    }
```

**Edit**

checked: it *is* working, though might look a bit weird with many indeterminate cells which are animated "in step". Just beware: the internal - in the ui delegate - animation state is undocumented, so there might be LAFs where it doesn't work at all (f.i. Substance, afair).

Comment: +1 This would be good start at re-factoring. The original is too convoluted, asymmetric and redundant to debug by inspection, at least for me.

Comment: Thank you that did it perfectly... never would have thought of that... great Thank you again.

Comment: [please are you know about ???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898028/what-happened-to-the-substance-laf), not possible to undelete this post, how I hate meta_SO, otherwise I sticked my  request about undelete there

Comment: @mKorbel no idea why that is deleted ... the only option is indeed to go to meta, always fun there ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra :-) eeeee [lets this decision for fun_factory](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177092/request-undelete-quite-valuable-thread-on-so)

Comment: @kleopatra eeeerght as we said lots of fun, doomed to disgrace and moodiness of this community, match drawn 5:5

Comment: @mKorbel thanks for the link, upvoted and commented - not much else we can do, I'm afraid ..

Answer (score 3):

probably you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), basically there are two ways

- use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html)
- use [Runnable#Thread()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9301453/714968)