# How to work like switch with Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a check box. If I checked it then I need to upload data to server. I have written this uploading logic in a Thread class. If I uncheck the checkbox I want to cancel the uploading and so on. The problem is that while trying to use the same thread if in some situation I am getting thread state as TERMINATED `(this.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED)`. What I need to do in this case? If thread state is new then I will call `start()` method. But in this case what do I need to do?

Comment: This means that the Thread finished doing its job and therefore cannot be used anymore. You need to create a new Thread.

Comment: If you need to interact between your GUI and another thread, it is maybe worth considering using SwingWorkers instead of a Thread. SwingWorkers can be cancelled like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113944/how-cancel-the-execution-of-a-swingworker

Comment: @assylias, Swing means nothing in Android.

Comment: As stated by @Caner, use AsyncTask instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: do not reuse thread.  Thread pooling has its advantages on big serverside sysems, but not on mobile phone there is no advantage.

Terminated thread is dead,  no action is necessary on your side anymore

Comment: It's not that complex. I use threads in Android regularly. I haven't seen something worst with threads...

Answer (score 0):

Use can try to use `AsyncTask` instead of thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html