# want to do progress bar of swing on button click

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, frame, buttonclick

Help me with this question. 
I want to add a proress bar on button click and while progress bar is running the main window(frame) should be closed or hidden. as progress finishes the main window should appear.

Comment: Check out the [progress bar tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) from Oracle

Answer (score 2):

there are two direct ways (implemented in APIs)

- use [ProgressMonitor / ProgressMonitorInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)
- use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for [notifiing progress in JProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113944/how-cancel-the-execution-of-a-swingworker/6114890#6114890)
- notice Swing GUi isn't thread safe, all output to Swing GUi must be done on [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example with a complete working code for your problem here:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/SwingProgressBar.shtml

You only need to add a `mainframe.setVisible(false);` and a `mainframe.setVisible(true);` to it, where mainframe is your main JFrame. You can do this modification in the "Create a timer" part, with a new `if (i==0)` and the existing `if (i==20)` statement. Than delete or modify tha rest of the code for your needs.

Comment: It's not a particularly useful example (IMHO). While the `Timer` ensures that the updates are performed within the EDT, the don't actually show how to effectively run a background to task so as not to block the EDT AND sync the progress update calls to the EDT